# How to use a return in a forEach loop in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array with multiple objects, which I want to use in a `*ngFor` loop.
I want to loop this with a `div` container and want to add a css class to the div container to show the containers next to each other. The css class is defined in the object and I need to convert it to a valid class, like `col-sm-6`.

So I created a function to search in the objects for a css class and convert this to a valid css class.
But my function only returns 1 css class, and not the correct css class for each object.

Let's look at my code:

Array:

```
elements = [
    {
        title: 'Test1',
        class: ["ColumnWidth3"]
    },
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        class: ["ColumnWidth9"]
    }
]
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let column of elements" [ngClass]="columnClass()">
    <h1>{{column.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

Function:

```
columnClass() {
    const columnClass = this.elements.filter((child: any) => child.class.includes('ColumnWidth') >= 0);

    columnClass.forEach(element => {
      this.item = element.class.find((class:any) => class.indexOf('ColumnWidth') >= 0).split('ColumnWidth').pop();
    });
    
    return 'col-sm-' + this.item;
  }
}
```

So what I want to get is the classes `col-sm-3` for the first object and `col-sm-9` for the second object. And add the css class of each object to the div container of that object.

But my function returns only `col-sm-9`.
How can I make sure that both objects get the correct class?

Comment: how does the column model look like? please add it to the question

Comment: what do you mean with column model? it is already in the question, see the Array part (elements is the model).

Comment: Why are you using array for the class property do may have more than one?

Comment: It consists of several objects, and the user can only define the class like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following example?

**Component:**

```js
 defineClass(classList: string[]) {
   const item = classList.find(x => x.startsWith("ColumnWidth"));
   return 'col-sm-' + item?.charAt(item.length - 1);
 }
```

**Template:**

```html
<div *ngFor="let column of elements" [ngClass]="defineClass(column.class)">
  <h1>{{column.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: If it had been that easy I would not ask the question. Unfortunately the user can only define the classes as: `ColumnWidthX`

Comment: nice solution, this works but I get an error on the const `item` at the return line.

`Object is possibly 'undefined'`